# Indesign file formatting using javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am getting extra spaces and early line break on the indesign file. Indesign file is generated programmatically using Javascript. I was trying following script   but nothing changed on indesign file.

```
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat="^\s?(.)";
app.changeTextPreferences.changeTo="$1";
```

Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should escape backslash in findWhat expression.

```
//@target "indesign"
app.findGrepPreferences            = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences          = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat   = "^\\s?(.)"; // -> this line
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "$1";
app.documents[0].changeGrep();
```

this snippet will works.

thank you.
mg